equivalent of sloped in decorations.markings - tikz
I would like to use the sloped syntax or something like it to achieve the same result when using decorations.markings.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% The sloped syntax works when not using decorations.markings
\draw (0,0) -- ++(2,1) node[pos=0.5,sloped] {a label};
% When using decorations.markings, I cannot use the same syntax to achieve the same result:
\draw
[
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[sloped] at (0,0) {a label};}
},
postaction=decorate
]
(0,-2) -- ++(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You could use the transform shape option:
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% The sloped syntax works when not using decorations.markings
\draw (0,0) -- ++(2,1) node[pos=0.5,sloped] {a label};
% When using decorations.markings, I cannot use the same syntax to achieve the same result:
\draw
[
decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[transform shape] at (0,0) {a label};}
},
postaction=decorate
]
(0,-2) -- ++(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


